# Bash breaking session/application gracefully

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, stdin

I'm running a PJSIP application and want to run it from a shell script. The problem is when i execute the script with;

./Downloads/pjproject-2.4.5/pjsip-apps/bin/pjsua-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0 --id=sip:line1@1.1.1.1 --registrar=sip:2.2.2.2 --realm=* --username=line1 --password=test --null-audio --duration=5 sip:88888888@2.2.2.2

The application dont quit by itself. So you I have to execute these command before the application quits gracefully

quit
enter (return)

How do I send "quit and return" to STDIN?

Comment: Does simply redirecting standard input from `/dev/null` work? `.../psjua .... </dev/null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends how the program handles input on stdin.
Did you try this:

```
echo "quit enter" | ./Downloads/pjproject-2.4.5/pjsip-apps/bin/pjsua-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0 ...
```

Comment: Thank yacc, I got the application to shutdown after 15 seconds with;  
echo "quit" ; sleep 15 | ./Downloads/pjproject-2.4.5/pjsip-apps/bin/pjsua-x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0 ...  
  
Because the PJSIP application had perform a task and when its done after 10 seconds the application need to get the 'quit' command through stdin. Thank for the help.